# cannot read property of undefined (reading 'pid') vs code C program issue

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, output, mingw

when i write a simple C code and run it it gives no output and then i stop it then it says:

> cannot read property of undefined (reading 'pid').

I reinstalled vs code and mingw as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the code of a [mre]. Format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field. (or see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more formatting options)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a JavaScript error message actually.

Check out [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) on how to set it up to run C code.